# Angular 9 MapboxGeocoder add marker doesn't work

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl, geocoder

I create a project with angular 9 and mapbox gl.
I have a problem with Geocoder, all works fine when I search place, but I try to set a point after Geocoder result like this: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/
I do the same, but the marker doesn't appear.

This is my code where I init my map and add geocoder:

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
    import {UserService} from '../../../user/service/user.service';    
    import * as MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
    import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl';
    import {environment} from '../../../../../environments/environment';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-sport-ad',
      templateUrl: './add-sport-ad.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-sport-ad.component.scss']
    })

    export class AddSportAdComponent implements OnInit {
      form: FormGroup;
      map: mapboxgl.Map;
      style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11';
      lat = 37.75;
      lng = -122.41;

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public userService: UserService) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.initForm();
        mapboxgl.accessToken = environment.mapbox.accessToken;

        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'map',
          style: this.style,
          zoom: 13,
          center: [this.lng, this.lat]
        });

        const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
          accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
          marker: {
            color: 'orange'
          },
          mapboxgl
        });

        this.map.addControl(geocoder);
        this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
      }
    }
```

If someone can help me thanks a lot :)

Comment: My 'Hello everybody' doesn't appear, i tried to edit it but doesn't works :( so Hello everybody haha

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the marker it is not adding automatically, so , to fix it this i manually added the marker.

by example:

```
new Marker().setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(this.map);
```

but you needed to save the marker position cause when you do another search you'll need remove the previous marker.

i did this: 
import

```
import { Marker } from "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js";
```

create a variable to store the marker

```
private lasMarker: Marker;
```

and then if there is an older marker i remove it and put the new one(if you don't remove the old one , this marker not removed automatically when you put another one)

```
if (this.lastMarker) this.lastMarker.remove();
this.lastMarker = new Marker().setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(this.getMapBox());
```